# Magento is adding "&register" in the URL of Onepage checkout when you click "Register"

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.7

I always worked with magento 1.5. There, when I click on REGISTER in the first step of Onepage checkout, the page automatically open the form for registration without reload.

Now I'm working on a store on magento 1.7 and I realized that is not working well. When I go in Onepage checkout and click on REGISTER, Magento reload the page, loads the form and add "& register" in the URL, exemple: www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/&register.

I've tried several ways to disable the reload and this "& register" .. I want to keep this page like in magento 1.5 .. I also saw other stores in Magento 1.7 that do not have this problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is cause of persistent module (since Magento 1.6)

Look at your template file:

```
app/design/frontend/[base/default]/[default/yourTheme]/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
```

This line of code:

```
<?php if ($this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout()): ?>
    <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
<?php else: ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('persistent/index/saveMethod'); ?>">
        <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="submit" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></span></span></button>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See the form action -> it is what makes your page reloaded

How does it change the template?

```
app/design/frontend/[base/default]/[default/yourTheme]/layout/persistent.xml
```

This line of code:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.login">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
        <block type="core/template" name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip" template="persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

If you're not using your persistent module, you can disable it by change app/etc/modules/Mage_Persistent.xml `<active>false</active>`

It looks like that module has been created neatly so it won't break anything if you disable it though I'm not really sure

Other way is to change the template, change that line of code into:

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo ($this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ? $this->__('Continue') : $this->__('Register')) ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I disabled the persistent cart for testing and the reload stoped. But I saw some stores like www.protoparadigm.com that uses Persistent cart (try to login/register) and do not reload in the checkout Register. Do you have some idea how to use persistent cart AND remove the checkout reload?

Comment: Basically, the `reload during register` only happen if it is not allowed for guest checkout. For your example, it is allowing guest checkout so it is not reloading the page. You can use ajax to prevent it reloading the page